# WPF Metro UI Charts - Negative Values

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml, modern-ui

I am trying to use the Library **WPF Metro UI Charts**, which is derivated from **Modern UI Charts**. However i'm having trouble with ***ClusteredColumnChart*** when i try to use use charts inside a *Page* instead of a *Window*. The graph always show negative axis in Y, even when there is no negative value. When i use the class ***Window*** it works properlly. 
The graph generated looks like this:

[image]

My XAML is this:

```
<GAChart:ClusteredColumnChart Style="{StaticResource MinimalChartStyle}"
                ChartTitle="{Binding Titulo}"
                ChartSubTitle="{Binding SubTitulo}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding selectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                          Width="400" Height="400"
                                          >
    <GAChart:ClusteredColumnChart.Series>
        <GAChart:ChartSeries
                        SeriesTitle="{Binding Dados.seriesDisplayName}"
                        DisplayMember="date"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Dados.Items}" 
                        ValueMember="amount" />
    </GAChart:ClusteredColumnChart.Series>
</GAChart:ClusteredColumnChart>
```

The codebehind is exactly the sample code provided in https://gamandelkowcharts.codeplex.com/.

Anyone knows a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is because by the time your page is creating your user control, it does not have the size of the window yet.

Try this, in your user control Sub New().

```
Public Sub RefreshUC()
Try
    Me.Measure(New Size(400, 400))
    Me.Arrange(New Rect(New Size(400, 400)))

    Dim GD As Grid = Me.Parent
    Dim KP As Page = GD.Parent

    KP.Content = New BarGraph

    KP.Measure(New Size(400, 400))
    KP.Arrange(New Rect(New Size(400, 400)))
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
End Sub
```